# Sending attach from a string with help PHP, Yii and Swift

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I need to send out email with attachment. 
Attachment I get from db. It's just HTML text. But I would like attach it to email as a file. I'm using Yii and YiiMail extenstion which is used SWift for that purpose.

When I attach it like that

```
 $message = new YiiMailMessage('Email subject', 'email body');

 $message->addTo($rcpt);
 $message->from = Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'];
 if(!empty($model->data)) 
     $message->addPart($model->data, 'text/html');
```

i get email but file not attached it is embedded ;(

Comment: Obvious question: did you check if `$model->data` is actually non-empty?

Comment: isn't `addPart` for alternative body? Anyway most of attachments should me save as temp file -> "attached" -> deleted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the docs here for attaching dynamic files, http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#attaching-dynamic-content

Comment: Link is broken, try this new one: https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/messages.html#attaching-dynamic-content